# attribution of anonymous members during constant structure initialisation

Tags: arrays, c, string, pragma

Assume the following simple structure in C:

```
struct entry {
    int id;
    const char *name;
};
```

Nothing special. Say I'd like to initialise an array of members globally. One would do:

```
const static struct entry entries[] = {
        {0, "foo", },
        {1, "bar", },
        {},
};
```

Nothing special. Now, say I'd like to place the `entries` array in the special section `special`. One would do:

```
const static struct entry entries[] __attribute__((__section__(".special"))) = {
        {0, "foo", },
        {1, "bar", },
        {},
};
```

Nothing special. Here comes my issue. I'd like to place the strings `foo` and `bar` in that section, too. Possible, but I want to do it **without** the use of intermediate variables.

The point is, that string literals are nothing else than pointers to the stored string placed in `.rodata`. I don't want to place them in `.rodata`, I want to place them somewhere else. But without the use of intermediate variables.

During code, one can use:

```
#define SPECIAL_STR(X) ({static const char __c[] __attribute__((__section__(".special")) = (X); &__c[0];})
```

With the usage:

```
void routine(void) {
    printf(SPECIAL_STR("foo"));
}
```

This will enforce a string to be located inside the section. But this fancy macro can only be used inside routines.

How can I place the strings `foo` and `bar` in the special section, **without** the need for intermediate variables? I don't want to have intermediate variables, as they make everything cumbersome.

What I would like to have is a macro like `SPECIAL_STR` that works as follows:

```
const static struct entry entries[] __attribute__((__section__(".special"))) = {
        {0, SPECIAL_STR("foo"), },
        {1, SPECIAL_STR("bar"), },
        {},
};
```

PS: I'd also like to avoid `#pragma rodata-name`, if possible :-)

Comment: This smells like there's an (for us) unknown problem behind the question. Why do you need something like that?

Comment: I'm implementing an operating system, where this array and its related content is only used once. The full section will be discarded after its usage, as it's only required during initalisation.

Comment: You are contemplating a long exotic attribute declaration so that you do not have to name the strings. Want a simple solution? Name the strings. That is, use the “intermediate variables” you do not want to use. There is no point using some complicated workaround to avoid a tiny little issue.

Answer (score 1):

The obvious solution is to swap  `const char *name;` for  `const char name [MAX_SIZE];`. Then you don't have to care about where/if the string literals are stored, since a copy of them will get uploaded into your special segment. It also sounds like what you are trying to make is an application with deterministic behavior, so having variably-sized strings might not be something you actually need?

Answer (score 1):

I do not think that what is asked can be accomplished 100%.

However, it is possible to initialize the array with named variables without having to manually synchronize two lists. This solution comes with the price of using [X macro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_macro) which will make the code obscure to read for people not familiar with that construct.

Anyway, doing this, the intermediate variables can be automatically defined and used for the array initialization as follows:

```
struct entry {
    int id;
    const char *name;
};

// Define the list of entries in the array
#define ENTRIES \
  X(0, "foo") \
  X(1, "bar")

// Automatically generate string variables for the names
#define X(ID, NAME) const char __attribute__((__section__(".special"))) SPECIAL_STRING_##ID[] = NAME;
ENTRIES
#undef X

// Finally, initialize the array
#define X(ID, NAME) {ID, SPECIAL_STRING_##ID},
const static struct entry entries[] __attribute__((__section__(".special"))) = {
        ENTRIES
        {},
};
#undef X
```

Changes to the `entries` array can then be done only by modifying the list in the `ENTRIES` macro.